# Write my own Custom OAuth External Login Provider

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, authentication, oauth, owin

I am developing a login interface for my work.  I need to implement a 3rd party login to one of our apps, and then save a token in the local storage so users are authorized.

The third party application would be equivalent to Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc.  I have some interal API methods and endpoints I can call and pass in username/password to authenticate with our DB.

**Question:** 
Can someone direct me to a walkthrough about how to implement a custom External Login Provider?  I see tons of documentation on how to implement facebook, twitter, etc.  But none for a custom app (Such as an app you have made previously.).

---

Currently I am working with this demo: http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/ + https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication (Source). I plan to 'rip' out Google/FB and insert in my own custom 3rd party login.

Any suggestions on how one can implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “3rd party” system is your existing authentication API that you mention.  If you want to use a token-based scheme, you’ll need to implement a token management layer in front of your existing system.  This layer will exchange credentials (verified by calling your existing system) for tokens.  It will also be responsible for verifying tokens that have been issued.

Your token layer will be responsible for retaining a list of issued tokens, for revocation purposes.

Rather than implementing this layer from scratch, you can use an open-source solution like [Kong](https://getkong.org/) and it’s various plugins.  Or consider a SaaS product, such as [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com), which can add OAuth2 functionality to your existing .Net application.  (Disclaimer: I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com)).

I've also written the following articles, which can be useful for understanding the overall token architecture:

[Token Based Authentication for Single Page Apps (SPAs)](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa/)

[Build Secure User Interfaces Using JSON Web Tokens (JWTs)](https://stormpath.com/blog/build-secure-user-interfaces-using-jwts/)

Hope this helps!